# Host ASP.NET (ashx) application from console for testing purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an existing ASP.NET application with few **ashx** and **asmx** services. How can I host them from console (or specifically from tests) for integration testing purposes?

Developers use IIS Express to run and debug them locally, so it's not an option to start IIS Express for that.

It is enough for me to skip the whole pipeline and invoke them directly, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to test web server, you can assume it's been tested by Microsoft and working fine, but you can test only your handler by invoking it from unit test. Take a look [here](http://www.kongsli.net/2009/05/03/aspnet-35-improving-testability-with-systemwebabstractions/) (Example #2) how to provider a fake HttpContext to your ProcessRequest handler method.  Also, try [this fake HttpContext](http://caioproiete.net/en/fake-mock-httpcontext-without-any-special-mocking-framework/):

```
HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(
    new HttpRequest(null, "http://tempuri.org", null),
    new HttpResponse(null));
```

For full end-to-end acceptance test you'll have to spin up IIS Express or even Casini server with command line:

```
START /D “C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\” /B WebDev.WebServer.EXE /port:5002 /path:”d:\Projects\myproject\” /vpath:”/Project”
```

There was never a good story of mocking and testing Web Forms page, handler and module components, but with OWIN that's mostly fixed, since it's very easy to spin up new server that's listening on a port from any console or service application

Comment: That sounds good. Here is even better alternative than starting Casini server w/ command line: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NUnitUnitTestingOfASPNETPagesBaseClassesControlsAndOtherWidgetryUsingCassiniASPNETWebMatrixVisualStudioWebDeveloper.aspx